# Multi select dropdown AngularJS - Options attribute unknown

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, multi-select

Currently I am using select for dropdown. I would like to change this as multiselect dropdown. But when I declare the multiselect dropdown I am getting error saying "unknown attribute Options"

The current code which is just a dropdown without multiselect.

```
                      <select class="form-control">      <option ng-repeat="item in CETIGroupList" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                        </select>
```

What I wrote for multiselect is

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="CETIGroupList" ></div>
```

Please help me creating a multiselect dropdown.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

include [loadsh.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js) , [bootstrap css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css) , [AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](https://rawgit.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/master/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js) in your app. Inject `angularjs-dropdown-multiselect`  in your app

```
angular.module('sampleApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect'])
```

in your HTML page

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example13data" selected-model="example13model" ></div>
```

in your Controller

```
$scope.example13model = [];
    $scope.example13data = [{
      id: 1,
      label: "David"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      label: "Jhon"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      label: "Lisa"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      label: "Nicole"
    }, {
      id: 5,
      label: "Danny"
    }];
```

Check out this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/8Ltae8pb/